# PHP: Find if 2 locations are conflicting in a matrix table

Tags: php, matrix

I have a map (array of arrays), and I have locations. Each location has start point and end point. Each point has X and Y.

Example:

```
$map = [
    ['0,0', '1,0', '2,0', '3,0', '4,0', '5,0', '6,0', '7,0', '8,0', '9,0'],
    ['0,1', '1,1', '2,1', '3,1', '4,1', '5,1', '6,1', '7,1', '8,1', '9,1'],
    ['0,2', '1,2', '2,2', '3,2', '4,2', '5,2', '6,2', '7,2', '8,2', '9,2'],
    ['0,3', '1,3', '2,3', '3,3', '4,3', '5,3', '6,3', '7,3', '8,3', '9,3'],
    ['0,4', '1,4', '2,4', '3,4', '4,4', '5,4', '6,4', '7,4', '8,4', '9,4'],
];

$location1 = '1,1,3,3';
$location2 = '7,0,9,1';
$location3 = '2,3,5,4';

hasConflict($location1, $location2);// Returns false = no conflict
hasConflict($location1, $location3);// Returns true = there is conflict
```

[image]

I'm not sure how to build the `hasConflict()` function. I could do nested loops and check each box, but I think there might be a mathematical/quicker way to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think at this the other way. When is it that the two areas ABCD and EFGH do *not* conflict?

```
    (A,B)-----+          (E,F)-----+
      |       |            |       |
      +------(C,D)         +------(G,H)
```

When the first is farther left than the second (thus C < E); when it is higher than the second (so D < F); when it is farther right (thus A > G); when it is lower (so B > H).

If it is not too left, nor too right, nor too high, nor too low, it must overlap.

In one-dimension, two ranges (A...C) and (E...G) are disjointed if C < E, or if A > G. So they intersect if this condition is false, and ((C >= E) && (A <= G)). This is perhaps easier to see:

```
     A---------C     E---------G                   C < E is true, A > G is false

                     E---------G   A--------C      C < E is false, A > G is true 

                A----E----C----G                   C < E is false, A > G is false

                     E---A-----G----C              C < E is false, A > G is false

                A----E---------G----C              C < E is false, A > G is false
```

In two dimensions, if there is an intersection on *both* X and Y axes, then the areas overlap. Therefore your condition for conflict is

```
(D >= F) && (B <= H) && (C >= E) && (A <= G)
```

This is the mathematical condition you were looking for (it works in higher dimensions as well).

Answer (score 2):

i Love the mathematical explanation of @LSemi and it deserves to be marked as the solution.However i have already written the PHP code so i post it too.

```
function hasConflict($location1,$location2){
    $location1=explode(',',$location1);
    $location2=explode(',',$location2);
    if($location1[0]>=$location2[0]&&$location1[0]<=$location2[2]&&$location1[1]>=$location2[1]&&$location1[1]<=$location2[3]) return true;
    if($location2[0]>=$location1[0]&&$location2[0]<=$location1[2]&&$location2[1]>=$location1[1]&&$location2[1]<=$location1[3]) return true;
    return false;
}

$map = [
    ['0,0', '1,0', '2,0', '3,0', '4,0', '5,0', '6,0', '7,0', '8,0', '9,0'],
    ['0,1', '1,1', '2,1', '3,1', '4,1', '5,1', '6,1', '7,1', '8,1', '9,1'],
    ['0,2', '1,2', '2,2', '3,2', '4,2', '5,2', '6,2', '7,2', '8,2', '9,2'],
    ['0,3', '1,3', '2,3', '3,3', '4,3', '5,3', '6,3', '7,3', '8,3', '9,3'],
    ['0,4', '1,4', '2,4', '3,4', '4,4', '5,4', '6,4', '7,4', '8,4', '9,4'],
];

$location1 = '1,1,3,3';
$location2 = '7,0,9,1';
$location3 = '2,3,5,4';

var_dump(hasConflict($location1, $location2));// Returns false = no conflict
var_dump(hasConflict($location1, $location3));// Returns true = there is conflict
```

Comment: it seems your code should return `true` for case "2,0,3,1 and 1,2,4,2", does not it?

Comment: you were right .i forgot some of the conditions.Edited.Thanks.